# TagHelper Task failed unexpectedly after upgrading to Visual studio 16.8.2

Tags: asp.net-core

After upgrading visual studio to 16.8.2 version. My project asp.net core showing this error
TagHelper Task failed unexpectedly. My project version is 2.2 .net core and I am a aware that Microsoft has stopped the support for 2.2 and 3.0 .net core. I just want to resolve this issue just for temporary one.

Answer (score 1):

- I Open cmd and write this: setx DOTNET_HOST_PATH "%ProgramFiles%\dotnet\dotnet.exe"
- Then Open C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk and delete the folder: NuGetFallbackFolder
- Lastly, I Restarted my pc